# Django “The view didn't return an HttpResponse object on the line 151”

Tags: python, django

I have this problem to HttpResponse on the line 151, i dont know what happen, i need your help. I think the error is on views.py but i dont know where is the error if i type the same code on the tutorial-book.

when i start this project only for lisen how work django, i read a tutorial and i type the same code between on book please help me.

this is my code on django.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegistroUserForm(forms.Form):
   username = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   password = forms.CharField(min_length=5, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   password2 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
   photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if User.objects.filter(username = username):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Nombre de usuario ya registrado!")
    return username

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email = email):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Ya existe un email Igual en la db!")
    return email

def clean_password2(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
    if password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Las contraseñas no coinciden")
    return password2
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .forms import RegistroUserForm
from .models import UserProfile

def registro_usuario_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data #cleaned_data obtiene los datos limpios y los pone en un diccionario
        # con pares clave/valor , donde la clave es el nombre del campo  cleaned_data.get("username") "ejemplo"
        #y el formulario es el ya ingresado
            username = cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = cleaned_data.get("password")
            email = cleaned_data.get("email")
            photo = cleaned_data.get("photo")
           user_model = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user_model.email = email
            user_model.save()
            user_profile = UserProfile()
            user_profile.user = user_model
            user_profile.photo = photo
            user_profile.save()
            return  redirect(reverse('accounts.gracias',kwargs={'username':username}))

    else:
        form = RegistroUserForm()
        context = {
    'form': form
    }
        return render(request, 'accounts/registro.html', context)

def gracias_view(request, username):
    return render(request, "accounts/gracias.html", {'username':username})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="profiles", blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I am beginner on django please help me

Comment: Which line is "line 151"?

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is? Preferably with what you've tried and researched about it so far

Answer (score 1):

The condition when the form is invalid is not handled. Can you try this, I have moved last two lines out of else block.

```
def registro_usuario_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data #cleaned_data obtiene los datos limpios y los pone en un diccionario
        # con pares clave/valor , donde la clave es el nombre del campo  cleaned_data.get("username") "ejemplo"
        #y el formulario es el ya ingresado
            username = cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = cleaned_data.get("password")
            email = cleaned_data.get("email")
            photo = cleaned_data.get("photo")
           user_model = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user_model.email = email
            user_model.save()
            user_profile = UserProfile()
            user_profile.user = user_model
            user_profile.photo = photo
            user_profile.save()
            return  redirect(reverse('accounts.gracias',kwargs={'username':username}))

    else:
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    context = {
    'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/registro.html', context)
```